# Loading thousands of images into Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

This Node-based desktop app loads roughly 3000 small images (~50KB) from the local disk to be visible all at once on the main screen. The app loads fine when I use Chrome (v. 66), but fails to load in Electron without an error reported to the console. The upper limit of images I am able to load is 1000.

I have included

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=8192')
```

before

```
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

and have also tried raising `--max-old-space-size` up to 16384, with the same result as reported above.

How might I maximize load performance with Electron? An image is added to the view every hour.

Comment: Electron 2.0.2 is running Chrome v. 61. I switched to using nw.js which uses Chrome v. 66 and did not have a problem loading my thousands of images. Because the posted question is about maximizing load performance in Electron, I'm going to leave it open instead of providing this as a solution.

Comment: I can think of one solution if the pictures or their containers always have the same height. Do they?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same height and width.

Comment: Ok, so you just want a scrollable container (eg div) with those pictures as a kind of gallery?

Comment: I have all the functionality set up in my javascript files. I load the images into an offscreen canvas and draw them on the visible canvas. This works well in Chrome v. 66 but the images would not all load in Electron, which uses Chromium v. 61. I switched to NW.js, which uses Chrome v. 66 and they all load well. But although I solved my issue by switching frameworks, the question remains about how one would maximize image load performance in Electron.